# Why is $dy/dx = y\cos(x)$ a non-linear differential equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I thought it would be linear because it can be made in the form $$dy/dx + P(x)y = Q(x).$$
$$dy/dx = y\cos(x),$$
$$dy/dx - y\cos(x) = 0,$$
with $P(x) = \cos(x)$ and $Q(x) = 0$.

Where am I wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: It is indeed a linear equation.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was linear DE also. The book I have said it is non-linear because it doesn't involve solely first order terms in y and y'. I don't understand what they mean. It can easily be put in the linear form.

Answer (score 0):

It is a linear, first order differential equation of the form $\displaystyle y' + y(-\cos x) = 0$ and it is easily solvable by multiplying throughout by the integrating factor $\displaystyle e^{\int (-\cos x)dx}$. Can you proceed?

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was linear DE also. The book I have said it is non-linear because it doesn't involve solely first order terms in y and y'. I don't understand what they mean. It can easily be put in the linear form.